# Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: during flash closing in Firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I got `Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL`

In this row:

```
var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
```

The bug appears in `Firefox+Chrome`, not  in  `IE`.

The problem occurs when I click BACK BUTTON which fires an javascript event to the flash, and in this special "exiting"  case the flash is trying to make a final POST request, but posting URL fails with `Firefox/Chrome`, working with IExplorer.     The apache does not receive request like it does with Iexplorer.

The same code works in firefox, when I  do not click BACK BUTTON of browser.

Comment: Could you test, and give URLLoader some extra time? Just to check.

Comment: Why don't you handle the event so you don't get that error? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html

Comment: And as your error states you might want to verify the URL

Comment: Well, the FLASH is closing down as user pressed browser BACK button, and it seems there is no time to do stuff.  Should I add some kind of sleep() or what function so that URL Loader has time to finish?

Comment: No it is impossible to "delay" leaving a window. I think you are making assumptions without verifying data. The error clearly states two things. 1) you have an unhandled event. 2) there is an issue with the url. Wouldn't you think it would be best to fix that first?

Comment: THe URL is OK,  its always same URL working OK with other browsers and  works OK  when  the window is not closing.   ALso, I can catch the error, but then my URL is simply not called  and the logout process does not work.

Comment: Check the event with HTTP status event